# Get rgb color with magick++ using c++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, rgb, magick++

I'm trying to get rgb from each pixel. But when I run my `C++` code I get on the shell for color  red something like this

55512

55255

55255

Why it is not a number between 0 and 255 as I exepected to be?

This is my code

```
Image image("image_test.jpg");
int w = image.columns();
int h = image.rows();

// get a "pixel cache" for the entire image
PixelPacket *pixels = image.getPixels(0, 0, w, h);

// now you can access single pixels like a vector
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
Color color = pixels[w * row + column];


for(row=0; row<h-1; row++){
          for(column=0; column<w-1; column++){
            Color color = pixels[w * row + column];
            cout<<pixels[w * row + column].red;
            image.syncPixels();
          }
        }
//image.syncPixels();

// write the image to file.
//image.write("test_modified.jpg");
```

Comment: maybe because your magick++ lib has been build with a quantum of 16bits so each component use the 16-bits scale, you can get back on 8bit using a simple shift of 8 bit to the right !

Comment: look [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-unix-installation.php) by default `--with-quantum-depth=16` so set it to 8 when you build ImageMagick

Comment: It doesn't work I added the -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=8 when I compile but the reults is even worse! there are strange symbols like this �

Comment: @Domenico I think that is because cout interprets 8 bit values as ascii code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do a bit of math to convert the pixel packet from the systems Quantum Depth to a format you want.

```cpp
Image image("image_test.jpg");
int w = image.columns();
int h = image.rows();
// Calc what your range is. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Color.html
// There's also other helpful macros, and definitions in ImageMagick's header files
int range = pow(2, image.modulusDepth());
assert(range > 0); // Better do some assertion/error checking here
// get a "pixel cache" for the entire image
PixelPacket *pixels = image.getPixels(0, 0, w, h);

// now you can access single pixels like a vector
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
Color color = pixels[w * row + column];


for(row=0; row<h-1; row++){
  for(column=0; column<w-1; column++){
    Color color = pixels[w * row + column];
      cout << (color.redQuantum() / range) << endl;
    }
}
```